# Response message is failed-Assertion Failed

Tags: assertion

When I am using jmeter it gives the message as "`Account created successfully`". So I added this message in Response assertion-->Response Message-->Contains.

But assertion is failed when giving the correct credential.When opening the assertion result, it shows the message as "`/Account created successfully/`".

Now how to remove the "/" from this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1.`Please check that there is no extra space in your message

`2.` Make sure you are coping the message from text response only,Please look below snapshot for reference only
[image]

`3.` "/" is not a problem it will come before your message when assertion fail